# Date and Time reduction in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, time

I am new with R and I am facing this problem:
I have a large dataset (both csv file and Rdata file) that contains some date and time columns.
[section of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skVYS.png)

I should do some calculation and some data visualization with it, but problems arises with the convertedTime column. I should visualize it as "minutes: seconds(with one decimal) as I indeed visualize them in the csv file if I open it with excel. I should work with the same format as shown in the excel file. 
[Excel sample of timeConverted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9hNo.png).

When I load the data in R (I have tried both formats) the convertedTime are expressed in their full format. How can I convert them into the %M:%OS1 ?

```
keyData <- read.csv('keyPressDataWithLaneDeviation.csv')
print(head(keyData))
library(dplyr)
keyDataNoError <- filter(keyData, typingErrorMadeOnTrial ==0)
print(head(keyDataNoError))
strptime(keyDataNoError$timeConverted, format = "%M:%0S1")
print(head(keyDataNoError))
```

After i filter the dataset i try to format the time without results. The output of the last 2 prints are identical. Where am I wrong?
Another thing that I tried to do is load the Rdata file instead. But with the Rdata file I don't even get decimals in the ConvertedTime column and i really do not understand why.

[Rdata file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDUcj.png)

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVBjo.png)

Comment: Please don't post data (or code) as images. Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of each of your datasets.)

Comment: You might want to check out the lubridate package. Specifically `lubridate::ms()` seems like it might help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `strftime`, not `strptime`.

```
strftime(keyDataNoError$timeConverted, format = "%M:%0S1")
```

e.g.:

```
a<-"2018-02-24 11:30:05.105"

strftime(a, format="%M:%OS1")
[1] "30:05.1"

strftime(a, format="%M:%OS3")
[1] "30:05.105"
strftime(a, format="%M:%OS5")
[1] "30:05.10500"
```

Note that `strftime` outputs a `character` class object, not a `POSIXt` class.

Comment: strftime(keyDataNoError$timeConverted, format = "%M:%0S1")
this script should convert the whole column right?

Comment: yep. Why don't you give it a try?